# How to iterate over a string of an array in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have an array of JSON objects, which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "author": "[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Frank'}]",
        "id": "1101"
    }
]
```

I want to use Python NumPy to convert the above to something like this:

```
[
    {
        "author": "John",
        "id": "1101"
    },
    {
        "author": "Frank",
        "id": "1101"
    }
]
```

The issue I'm facing is that the value of `author` key is a string, so I can't iterate over it to create the new structure. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why would you use `numpy` here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely `eval` the string value.

```py
import ast
import json

data = '''\
[
    {
        "author": "[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Frank'}]",
        "id": "1101"
    }
]
'''

arr = json.loads(data)

out = []

for d in arr:
    id_ = d['id']
    names = ast.literal_eval(d['author'])
    for a in names:
        name = a['name']
        out.append({'author': name, 'id': id_})

print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Numpy ?? Very simple to do it :

```py
import json
new_obj = json.loads(your_list[0]['author']])
```